# Using NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED vs getNextAlarmClock

Tags: android, alarm

I was using the NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED method for obtaining the next alarm and display it on a widget. Since the setting is deprecated, I decided to do a check on the API version and if 21 or over, to use the new getNextAlarmClock() function. The problem is that the getNextAlarmClock function does not detect alarms set by all 3rd party applications (whereas the old method did). As stated in the documentation,

> The alarm clocks considered are those scheduled by
>   setAlarmClock(AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo, PendingIntent) from any
>   package of the calling user

Is there a way to get these alarms too other than using the deprecated settings? Will there be a problem if I use the old method and set the compile SDK version of the app to the latest one, 23?